# how to know when dynamic component has fully loaded

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

So I'm loading some components dynamically like so:

```
const Page0 = () => import("@/components/pages/tutorial/Pages/Page0")
const Page1 = () => import("@/components/pages/tutorial/Pages/Page1")
```

There are 10 more pages like this, which will be called depending on the route params.

I was wondering how I would know if a certain Page was loaded, for the purposes of creating a loading screen, and how I would know when it was being switched.

This is how I'm using it altogether.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <component :is="current_page"></component>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    const Page0 = () => import("@/components/pages/tutorial/Pages/Page0/index.vue")
    const Page1 = () => import("@/components/pages/tutorial/Pages/Page1/index.vue")

    export default {
        scrollToTop:
            true,
        components:
            {
                Page0,
                Page1,
            },
        computed:
            {
                current_page ()
                {
                    return "Page" + this.page
                }
            },
        asyncData ({
            route, store, env, params, query, req, res, redirect, error
        })
        {
            return {
                page:
                    params.page
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using vue-router?

Comment: @Phil yes, but I'm changing the pages through the param field, so something like `/tutorial/page/1`, `/tutorial/page/2`, which is in the format of `/tutorial/page/:id`

Comment: I think `import()` returns a promise, if so usual `.then()` might work.

Comment: @RichardMatsen I'm calling it in combination with `computed` and `components`. I've updated to show what I'm doing, so I'm not sure how I would fit a `.then` or `await` into there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *how to know when dynamic component has fully loaded ?*

You can use `@hook:mounted` for **every component dynamic or not** to indicate that the component is loaded.

e.g.

```
<component :is="current_page" @hook:mounted="doSomething"></component>
```

Check [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-0o8ff)

Comment: Kewl. I didn't know the lifecycle hooks emit custom events like that. Is that officially documented somewhere?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not documented somewhere as far as I know.

Comment: [Vue.js Component Hooks as Events](https://alligator.io/vuejs/component-event-hooks/)

Comment: @RichardMatsen We're talking about official docs here. Thanks for the link though.

Comment: I notice your imports aren't dynamic (in codesandbox), switched them over but it's not playing nice so far.

Comment: @RichardMatsen I was not able to do dynamic imports in code sandbox. I think if you try locally in your machine should work.

Comment: Cheers, that is a useful feature for managing webpack bundles.